# jQuery range selector

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm searching to filter elements with a range. Exemple, with a element list:

```
<ul>
  <li data-price="25">Foo</li>
  <li data-price="50">Bar</li>
  <li data-price="125">Baz</li>
  <li data-price="150">Biz</li>
</ul>
```

I want to extract all li with data-price >= **50** and <= **125**. Does exist a selector who can do it simply ? If not What can be a simple way to do it ?

Comment: you can also use `$(this).attr('data-price') `

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `.filter()` function:

```
$('ul li').filter(function(){
  return($(this).data('price')>=50 && $(this).data('price')<=125)
});
```

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pPNs5/)**

Answer (score 0):

Use js to loop all `li` elements and check for `data('price') >= 50 && data('price') <= 125`.

jQuery:

```
var list = [];
$.each($('ul > li'), function(){
    if ($(this).data('price') >= 50 && $(this).data('price') <= 125) {
       list.push($(this));
    }
});
```

Comment: why making things complex instead of using `.filter()`..?

Comment: @oGeez: Array does, *which is what they are using*. The code is valid (if not the most efficient): http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/pPNs5/1/

Comment: An alternative to an array is to start with an empty jQuery object `$()` and use `.add` to append matches. In this particular case `Filter` is definitely a better option.